# Toggeling Touch by external keyboard

Tags: android, input, keyboard, touch, firmware

I am building a firmware for visually disabled people. I have to disable touch screen as and when the external key board is connected. And toggle it with `Alt + T` . For this I have a `static volatile` flag in View class called misTouchScreenEnabled. Upon plug in of external keyboard I return `false` from `dispatchTouchEvent()`. 
 In View Class :

```
/*
* A register to hold the status of touch screen
*
*{@hide}
*/
public static volatile boolean misTouchScreenEnabled = false;

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
Log.d ("CnxsTA","View :: Into dispatchTouchEvent");
// Added by Harsh Vardhan 05102013 
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (config.keyboard != Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS)
{
    // And if the device has a hard keyboard, even if it is
    // currently hidden, don't pass the touch events to the view
    if(!mIsTouchScreenEnabled)
    {
        Log.d ("CnxsTA","View :: Into dispatchTouchEvent :: Returning False");
        return false;
    }
    }
// Added By Harsh Vardhan
// Some Other Code...
}
```

In Launcher I catch the `ALT + T` in `dispatchTouchEvent()` and toggle the flag using reflection:

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_T:
    {
        //Added By Harsh Vardhan 31052013
        Log.d ("CnxsTA","Launcher :: onKeyDown :: T pressed");

        if ((event.getMetaState() & KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON) == KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON)
        {
            Object s;
            try
            {
                Log.d ("CnxsTA","Launcher :: In onKeyDown :: In isAltPressed");
                s = ToogleTouchScreen(Class.forName("android.view.View"), "mIsTouchScreenEnabled");
                if (s instanceof Boolean)
                {
                    boolean v = ((Boolean) s).booleanValue();
                    //do something
                    Log.d ("CnxsTA","Launcher :: onKeyDown :: In isAltPressed :: Toggling touchscreen enable flag :: " + v);
                    if (accessibilityEnabled)
                    {
                        if (mTts != null)
                        {
                            if (v)
                                mTts.speak("Touch Screen enabled", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            else
                                mTts.speak("Touch Screen disabled", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (s == null)
                {
                    //do something
                    Log.d ("CnxsTA","Launcher :: onKeyDown :: S is Null");
                }
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        return true;
        //break;
        //Added By Harsh Vardhan 31052013
    }
```

This works well for the Launcher and its workspace, ie. the touch gets enabled and disabled when `ALT + T` is pressed. But the Panel in the bottom containing the back, home, recent apps and notifications remains unresponsive on touch and so is the UI in the application; though in Exploration Mode the Icons names are spoken on touch but the touch is not implemented. And it all retains to normal sate once the external keyboard is removed.

I think the reason behind this could be that the StatusBar Class and Other Classes extending the `View` which are taking the `flag` to be false only has cached the whole class or the variables and methods and is not referring to main memory where the flags have been toggled. I am aware that I have made the flag `volatile`.
I know that my flag gets toggle as I could confirm this from `logcat`.
 Please suggest me the direction I could solve this. Thanking in advance.

Comment: I know for sure now that other threads are not taking the updated value as now I have marked the boolean flag as true by default and the whole behavior has been reciprocated, now the touch works in status bar and applications. For that I have read that `volatile` keyword is enough to force-refer variables from main memory; but that just doesn't seem to work.